# docker-compose - Not able to connect to postgres db

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run the docker-compose command on Jenkins slave but it fails while running the command pytest tests/integration.
The command run integration tests with backend as postgres.
Dockerfile is

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  test:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres_db
    environment:
      PG_UNITTEST_DB: "postgresql://testuser:testpassword@postgres_db/testdb"
    command: pytest tests/integration
  postgres_db:
    image:  postgis/postgis
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: testpassword
      POSTGRES_USER: testuser
      POSTGRES_DB: testdb
```

And the error I am getting is

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "postgres_db" (172.19.0.2) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I tried exposing port 5432 in docker-compose file in postgres_db section but didn't help. The same code works fine locally. The command I run is

```
docker-compose -f tests/integration/docker-compose.yml up --build --exit-code-from test
```

Comment: ```command: bash -c 'while !</dev/tcp/postgres_db/5432; do sleep 1; done; pytest tests/integration'```
this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Postgres takes a moment to start up before it can start servicing requests. It is likely that your  code in the `test` container is attempting to connect before Postgres is ready.

Your best option is probably to add some retry logic to your integration test. E.g., add something to your[setup method](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/xunit_setup.html) that loops until it is able to establish a successful database connection.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the order of starting the service so that your postgres container is up before the test container. For detailed info, you can refer to the docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/